# Spring <constructor-arg> element must specify a ref or value

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

I'm having a problem with Spring and constructor injection. I want to create dynamically objects with a name (`String`) and special id (`long`).

But when the spring.xml file is loaded an exception occurs.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [long]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

My spring.xml:

```
    <bean id="someBean" class="someClass" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value=""/>       
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="long" value=""/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So what's wrong there? The constructor-arg has index 1 (and not 0, as the exception says)

Comment: Have you tried with `type="java.lang.Long"`?

Comment: Yes, i tried that also. I removed the index too. But no improvements

Comment: you should also share how your constructor really looks like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the constructor arguments you can use either a primitive type `long` and value `0`, or a wrapper type `java.lang.Long` and an empty value. Also, to keep things under control, I would set a value of the second argument explicitly to 0.

Comment: Ok, i switched from value="" to value="0". But the problem still exists

Comment: Could you please add the code of the constructor of `someClass` to your post? Are you sure that you pass the arguments in the correct order?

Comment: Well, thats pretty embarrassing.. The constructor was like (id, name) and i called (name, id).