# Get bean with specific Arguments to constructor in Spring

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

assume I have that class

```
public Student{
 private String name;
 private Address address;

 public Student(String fName, Address address){
  name = fname;
  this.address = address;
}
```

I defined this class within Spring configuration as

```
 <bean name="studentInstance" class="StackOverFlow.Student"/>
```

now i'd like to use getBean with parameter I will pass to constructor.
equal to `Student s = new Student(name,address)`
I know Spring supplies a methond getBean(class_name,parms....)
however I dont know how I should  config Spring.xml configuration file.
I would like to avoid using Setter and getter in order to fill a new bean.

I found lots of example of how to define `</constructor-arg>` within the xml but each time it was with default values. here I let the user to enter different values for each object.
I'd like to use 
`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(Spring.xml file path);
Student s= (Student)context.getBean("studentInstance",name,address);`

**I need help with the configuration file only**

**Thanks in Advance!!**

I already checked those links :
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784960/spring-and-passing-parameters-to-factory-method-in-runtime) [Link2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) [Link3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators) [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829162/spring-bean-instantiation-by-passing-constructor-args)

~~~~~Edit ~~~~~~~

Solved! constructor-injection is not needed here
I just added prototype  scope to my bean as shown below.

```
<bean name="carInstance" class="MainApp.bl.GasStation.Car" scope="prototype"/>
```

Comment: Side note, Spring creates Singleton of a bean by default. If you need more instances, first you will have to declare your bean as a prototype.

Comment: Wow!! I just added  scope="prototype" to my bean and everything worked like magic!!!

why it is not mentioned or shown anywhere!

tnx brother!

Comment: If this helped you, you may accept the answer by clicking gray check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, such bean must obviously be declared as prototype.

> The Prototype scopes a single bean definition to have any number of object instances. If scope is set to prototype, the Spring IoC container creates new bean instance of the object every time a request for that specific bean is made 
>   <

`Object getBean(String name, Object... args)throws BeansException`

> Return an instance, which may be shared or independent, of the specified bean.
>   Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method arguments, overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the bean definition.

Refer to following question for configuration:

[Spring <constructor-arg> element must specify a ref or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260258/spring-constructor-arg-element-must-specify-a-ref-or-value)

Note, you will have to wrap primitives into their Wrapper objects to avoid having predefined values when object is created.